# Hover over a <span> value button and click on drop down option

Tags: html, vba

I have been working on this all day but couldn't make it work. I am navigating a website with VBA. I now have to hover over a span button and click on the pause link option.

Here is the HTML code for the button/menu :

```html
<span class='icon-gear'></span>
  <ul class='tooltip-menu gearbox'>
    <li class='action_visibility pause '>
      <a href="#" class="pause_link">Kill</a>
    </li>
    <li class='action_visibility unpause hide'>
      <a href="#" class="unpause_link">Unpause</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The VBA code I have been writing was:

```
For Each obj In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
  If obj.innerText = "Kill" Then
    obj.parentElement.Click
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

But without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: your text is inside an anchor so you need to change the `span` to `a` in `getElementsByTagName("span")`

Comment: Thank you I modified as follow and worked like a charm :    For Each obj In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
      If obj.className = "pause_link" Then
        obj.Click
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for "objects" inside the span tag.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried to get to the objects directly without success either. I figure it is because they do not appear less I hover over the span button. What do you think ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.